# error in concatenating the strings in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, concatenation

When I am trying to run this code. I'm getting this error "C2110: '+' : cannot add two pointers". Can anyone just tell me what is wrong in the code?

```
string Msg;
getline(cin, Msg);

string output;
output = "<Rvc>\n"+"<Msg>"+Msg+"< / Msg>\n";
```

Comment: what about of using `fmtlib` (C++20): string output = fmt::format("<Rvc>\n<Msg>{}< / Msg>\n", Msg);

Answer (score 1):

[C-style string literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) are not `std::string`s. `"<Rvc>\n"` and `"<Msg>"` are of type `const char[]` and could decay to pointers (i.e. `const char*`). Adding on pointers doesn't make sense.

You can just

```
output = "<Rvc>\n<Msg>"+Msg+"< / Msg>\n";
```

Then the overloaded [`operator+` for `std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B) taking `const char*` and `std::string` will be used.